# How to get SQL statements using open telemetry and auto-instrumentation on IIS

Tags: open-telemetry

I would like to get the SQL statements executed when using the OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.SqlClient library, it is documented that this is possible:

https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.SqlClient/README.md#net-framework

But I'm using the IIS auto instrumentation to enable tracing: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/net/automatic/#instrument-an-aspnet-application-deployed-on-iis

So I'm not sure how to enable the option I'd like to use. Does anyone know how or any docs that might explain how I can achieve what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [OpenTelemetry .NET Automatic Instrumentation v1.4.0+](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet-instrumentation/releases/tag/v1.4.0).
It is possible to enable this functionality by `OTEL_DOTNET_AUTO_SQLCLIENT_SET_DBSTATEMENT_FOR_TEXT` environmental variable.

Ref. [documentation](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet-instrumentation/blob/v1.4.0/docs/config.md#instrumentation-options).

Comment: thanks for this, it looks like we're being caught by the .net framework restriction mentioned in the docs as after enabling the env var I'm still not seeing the sql statements